# TYPO3: Add meta header noindex from extension php code

Tags: typo3

TYPO3 vers. 4.5
Doing an extension. Based on a condition in my extension class I need to add a noindex header.

This should work - but does not:

```
header('X-Robots-Tag: noindex,nofollow');
```

How can I make TYPO3 accept custom headers?

BR. Anders

**UPDATE:**
These lines work much just fine. Case closed:

```
// MAY BE DUBLICATE CONTENT - DO NOT LET GOOGLE INDEX
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->additionalHeaderData['tx_myext'] = '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">';
```

Comment: Make sure, that you don't output any content, before sending header. TYPO3 doesn't make any content output before calling your extension's code. Check with `headers_sent($file, $line)`, if headers are already sent and where, if so.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It actually worked fine after added the header the "TYPO3-way" and not just the normal$GLOBALS['TSFE']->additionalHeaderData['tx_myext'] = '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just has to be added the TYPO3-way:

```
//print 'MAY BE DUBLICATE CONTENT - DO NOT LET GOOGLE INDEX';
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->additionalHeaderData['tx_myext'] = '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">';
```